# make a pseudo device like /dev/random that outputs primes?

Tags: python, devices, character-device

/dev/primes is what I want without writing C code just python which I have known and easily written the program.

The device file should be similar to /dev/urandom that outputs primes instead of random stream!!

I am excited if linux could do it!

Comment: Adding new devices is not trivial. Writing a Python program that reads ```/dev/urandom``` and outputs only primes should be straightforward; try that.

Comment: How is it straightforward?

Comment: @Scott I never said I wanted a new device... i could use a device file instead. In situations where mknod or other linux utilities regarding kernel can help me generate new device files that maps to a python or a C program that prints primes.

Comment: @Scott although i'd love to know how to make /dev/urandom connect to my python program to output primes.

Comment: @Scott you say its straightforward but provided no hints on it...

Comment: What kind of primes do you want to output? Prime sequence? Random 2048-bit primes?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. `/dev/urandom` is implemented by the kernel (as a character device), if you want a similar `/dev/primes` you would have to extend the kernel (coding in C) to implement a similar character device. This code would almost surely not make it upstream, since this feature doesn't really belong in the kernel and should instead be implemented in userspace.

Comment: If you implement it in userspace, you can make its user interface similar to `/dev/urandom` in that you could use something like a pipe (see `mkfifo`) and write a Python program that continuously writes primes to this pipe. It will block until the pipe is full. Consuming from a `/dev/primes` pipe would be similar to consuming `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Having said that, a character interface is probably a very poor interface for getting primes, since you usually want to get prime numbers of more than one byte (I'm thinking large primes) and with a character device or a pipe there's a lot that could go wrong, a consumer could do a short read, get it misaligned. There are better ways to create an interface to a prime generator that makes it hard to misuse it. But probably the best interface is to *simply do it in-process, using a library*. That library would read from `/dev/urandom` to get entropy to generate primes!

Comment: Wow.  (1) If I had felt like writing an answer, I would have written an answer.  I didn’t feel like writing an answer, so I wrote a comment.  Comments are not supposed to be complete answers.  (2) Since you seem to want to be able to generate a random stream of primes (or a stream of random primes), I suggested an approach that could help you achieve the result you want.  (3) You didn’t ask how to write a Python program that reads `/dev/urandom` and outputs only primes, so I felt no urge to explain how to do it. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Now that you are (sort-of) asking that, my response is: it should be straightforward.  Do some research, and try to do it. If you get stuck, ask us a specific question.   (5) The English of your question is unclear, but your first paragraph seems to be saying that you can easily write Python programs.  If that’s true, I wouldn’t expect you to need hints.   (6) You say “I never said I wanted a new device.”  Before you asked this question, did you do a search for `/dev/randomprime` or something similar?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you had, you would have found nothing, because there’s no such thing.  So, by saying that you want a pseudo device like ```/dev/random``` that outputs primes, you ***are*** saying that you want a *new* device. (7) You say “I never said I wanted a new device ... I could use a device file instead.” … Well, “In Unix, everything is a file.”  We often say “device” when we mean “device file” or “pseudo-device”.  Did you believe that I was talking about a piece of hardware?

Answer (score 2):

#### What you want is not possible.

Character devices are provided by Linux kernel modules.
Linux kernel modules are written in C.
You can, in theory, use a programming language other than C. But your program needs to be compiled into a binary that can be loaded into the kernel. In particular, you need to define an initialization handler, an exit handler, as well as the functions `dev_open`, `dev_read`, `dev_release` with well-defined signatures.
You cannot do this in Python (truly exotic approaches may exist, but I do not know of any).

For more information on how to write a Linux kernel module in C, confer to [any guide](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device) (contents not inserted here due to copyright) you like.